# how to do keypress event in jpanel text field?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keypress, joptionpane

when i select something in combobox :

[image]

it show joptionPane Dialog box wiht two inputs.

[image]

here i want to first focusing amount field and then, when i entered in amount field its goes to no of App field then enter go to OK .

Here is my code for JOption Dialog:

```
JTextField xField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField yField = new JTextField(5);
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Amount:"));
myPanel.add(xField);
myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
myPanel.add(new JLabel("No of App:"));
myPanel.add(yField);
int value = 0;
xField.requestFocus();
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "Please Enter Amount and No.of app", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: How do you know when the user is finished entering the amount?

Comment: Perhaps it's more appropriate to create a new `JDialog` instead of using a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: i'm already do that validation. but i want how to keypress event here

Comment: (as you know very well) for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: use JFormattedTextField or JSpinner for Numbers in Swing

Comment: @CanadianDavid can you send me correct link?

Comment: In order to do this `JOptionPane`, you'd need to override the `createDialog` method, attach a `WindowFocusListener` to it and then try and set focus to the required field, this might require a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` as the whole API seems hell bent on setting the initial value to have focus...

Answer (score 0):

You simply try to focus a component which is not layout in a window.

Replace

```
xField.requestFocus();
```

by

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    xField.requestFocusInWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. You can also try to listen all WindowEvents using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener and on window opened try to focus your field

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `JDialog` on the event that an item has changed to a new item. Then, you can get values entered in the `JDialog` and appropriately set the information in your parent. If you want to change the order of focus, use a custom focus policy. If you want to change the traversal focus key to the Enter key, you should re-map the key so that it reacts the same as the Tab key. There are several resources online and on this site with information on how to do that.

You should note that the default focus traversal policy is dependent on the order in which you add you elements to your content panel.

I have created a simple example for you on using a `JDialog`:

[image: The initial screen]
[image: The JDialog]
[image: The new screen with the entered information]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class RankSelection extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    RankSelection frame = new RankSelection();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public RankSelection() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"Slave", "Peasant", "Minion", "Knight", "Bishop", "Prince", "Coder King"}));
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    Amount amount = new Amount();
                    textField.setText(Integer.toString((Integer) amount.getStinkiness().getValue()));
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lblYourRank = new JLabel("Your Rank");
        contentPane.add(lblYourRank, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel lblYourStinkiness = new JLabel("Your Stinkiness:");
        panel.add(lblYourStinkiness);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setEnabled(false);
        textField.setText("0");
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        pack();
    }

}
```

The custom `JDialog`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Amount extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JSpinner amount;
    private JSpinner stinkiness;

    public Amount() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lblAmount = new JLabel("Amount:");
        amount = new JSpinner();
        JLabel lblStinkiness = new JLabel("Stinkiness:");
        stinkiness = new JSpinner();

        contentPanel.add(lblAmount);
        contentPanel.add(amount);
        contentPanel.add(lblStinkiness);
        contentPanel.add(stinkiness);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
        buttonPane.add(okButton);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public JSpinner getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public JSpinner getStinkiness() {
        return stinkiness;
    }

}
```